# Elements in two different columns

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a picture and on the left hand side I want to add three paragraphs.
This is my HTML:

```
<md-toolbar layout-align="center center">
        <h3>Traffic Light Component</h3>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-grid-list md-cols="2" md-row-height="250px" md-row-width="1000px">

        <div layout="row" layout-margin>
            <div id="a" flex="25">
                <div id="1">
                    <p>hii1</p>
                </div>

                <div id="2">
                    <p>HIIIIII</p>
                </div>

                <div id="3">
                    <p>tybiurhj</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
                <div id="b">
                    <md-grid-tile class="image">
                        <img ng-src="{{getStatus(caselist)}}" width="80" height="200"/>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

Its displaying them but is it possible to move them to the center?

All the help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the CSS property `text-align:CENTER;` will make it so the paragraphs and images will be centered like so.

```css
div#a, div#b{
  text-align:CENTER;  
}
```

```html
<md-toolbar layout-align="center center">
        <h3>Traffic Light Component</h3>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-grid-list md-cols="2" md-row-height="250px" md-row-width="1000px">

        <div layout="row" layout-margin>
            <div id="a" flex="25">
                <div id="1">
                    <p>hii1</p>
                </div>

                <div id="2">
                    <p>HIIIIII</p>
                </div>

                <div id="3">
                    <p>tybiurhj</p>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
                <div id="b">
                    <md-grid-tile class="image">
                        <img ng-src="{{getStatus(caselist)}}" width="80" height="200"/>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </md-grid-list>
</div>
```

Comment: Which elements do you want to center?

Comment: the <div id="a"> and b

Comment: I have edited my snippet, could you try to run it and see if it works now.

Comment: Now they are in the center but they are but they are on top of each other.

Comment: So, you want all text and images in line with each other, or just div a and div b.

Comment: Yes I want the text and the images to be in line.

Comment: Yes but the title is not that important